# How to reduce the margin between 'leading' and 'title' for ListTile ? Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

The margin between leading and title is too much;

[image]

How to decrease it;
I have tried several ways:

1. warp the leading with container and set margin right negative;
2. warp the title and set padding-left

however, it does not work at all;
is there any solution, i do need help

Comment: If you have used Divider the set height to 0, see example https://stackoverflow.com/a/63278039/11827756

Comment: You can try using a FlatButton https://stackoverflow.com/a/64515086/1354367

Comment: With the release of Flutter 2.0.0, it would appear [@CopsOnRoad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65850534/638153) would be worthy consideration for this question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you're ultimately better off building your own containers - there's nothing special or complicated about ListTile.  that way you can easily customize things like the spacing between a title and a button.  just use something like so:

```
  Container(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0, horizontal: 6.0),
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0),

    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
    ),

    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[

                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(myLeadingIcon),
                    onPressed: () => {},
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0)),
                  Text(_myTitle),
                ],
              ),
    ...
```

Comment: thanks. it seems the only approach to achieve that; i will give a try.

Answer (score 17):

**UPDATE**

Now you can also use the following propertier:

1. `horizontalTitleGap` - Between *title* and *leading*
2. `minVerticalPadding` - Between *title* and *subtitle*
3. `minLeadingWidth` - Minimum width of *leading*
4. `contentPadding` - Internal padding

**OLD**

You can use the `visualDensity` property to reduce the space.

```
ListTile(
    visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: -4, vertical: 0),
    title: Text("xyz")
);
```

The  `visualDensity` value can be changed from `-4.0 to 4.0`. Lower the value, more compact the view.

P.S. This solution is similar to a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63504719/6747251)

*This question is about the gap between `leading` and `title`. But the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63504719/6747251) is about `top/bottom` spacing*

Answer (score 16):

The only answer that worked for me is to Matrix transform the title widget.

Here, the title text padding is decreased by 16.

```dart
ListTile(
  leading: Icon(icon),
  title: Transform(
              transform: Matrix4.translationValues(-16, 0.0, 0.0),
              child: Text("Title text",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: textPrimary)),
              ),
);
```

Source: [How to set the padding between leading and title from Flutter ListTile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59463391/how-to-set-the-padding-between-leading-and-title-from-flutter-listtile)

Comment: This works!! Thanks for saving my time friend.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use leading just use Row inside title

```
title: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
       Icon(Icons.location_on,size: 15,color:ThemeManager.mainContentColor,),
       SizedBox(width: 8,),
       Text('DEMO'),
    ],
),
```

Comment: in this case, why would one bother using ListTile at all? But the idea is right, ListTile is just a small layout made of column and rows with built-in paddings

Answer (score 6):

Inside ListTile, Use contentPadding : EdgeInsets.fromLTRB() 
you can then tweak the R value to suit your design.

An example with a Container:

```
Container(
        child: ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 250.0, 0.0),
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
            child: Text('A'),
          ),
          trailing: Text(
            'Any Text here',
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontSize: 16.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: This does not affect the spacing between the `leading` and `trailing` widgets.

Comment: Seriously, why isn't this the best solution? I was searching on how to remove the edges padding of the ListTile to make it aligned with the other content below it, I was about to give up and make my own customized widget and then this is the only solution that worked for me! `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0)`. Thanks a LOT!!

Comment: @MahmoudEidarous this isn't the best solution because, although it may have helped you, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Question is related to reduce gap between leading and title in listtile while you are suggesting contentpadding which only applied on listtile as padding from left, top, right and bottom.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Set `minLeadingWidth` to `0`.

```dart
ListTile(
  minLeadingWidth: 0, // <-- Set this. 
  leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
  title: Text('Settings'),
)
```

Comment: This seems to work, but I can't find it documented anywhere. I was really hoping that there would also be a `minTrailingWidth`, but it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: @BananaNeil 'minLeadingWidth' appears to have just been added as part of Flutter `2.0.0`, which looks like it just [released on 3/3/21](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases). I'm on the Stable channel and `minLeadingWidth` was available as a property today, whereas it wasn't yesterday. No idea about documentation, but here was the [commit on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/8cb266511897d79e6d7d60c08c0e425f4cdaf433#diff-c4ef7c798c820ecda6cab38be1c2d619d5349dc478889f3a54ebbe07f60c11f2).

Answer (score 5):

I think it's quite late to reply to this, but I think this can help others. I faced similar kind of problem. The below code helped me to solve this:

```
Card(
  child: ListTile(
    leading: Icon(
      Icons.call,
      color: Colors.teal,
      size: 20
    ),
    title: Align(
      child: Text(
          "xxxxxxxxxx"
      ),
      alignment: Alignment(-1.3, 0),
    ),
    dense: true,
  )
```

So, basically combination of `Alignment property to title` and `dense: true` eventually helped me to solve this.

> Note: Use alignment value according to your use case.

I hope this will help you!

Comment: this breaks the text alignment with other items in the list...

Answer (score 3):

You can set horizontalTileGap

> `ListTile( horizontalTitleGap: 0, //Set this.  minLeadingWidth: 0, leading: Icon(Icons.settings), title: Text('Settings'),)`

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem these days, and finally I published one package which may can solve this problem.

The package is available at https://pub.dev/packages/list_tile_more_customizable, and with this package we can set the horizontalTitleGap, and when it has been set to 0.0(zero), the padding between leading and title will become zero.

Usage:

```
ListTileMoreCustomizable(
    title: Text("Title"),
    trailing: Icon(Icons.people),
    horizontalTitleGap: 0.0, // This horizontalTitleGap can set the margin between 'leading' and 'title' and also between 'trailing' and 'title'.
    onTap: (details){},
    onLongPress: (details){},
);
```

Edited:
This method works great for me, and also the code is available at https://github.com/Playhi/list_tile_more_customizable (the raw code is too long), I'm hard to understand why one user down-voted the answer without submitting any problems on it.

Answer (score 2):

Set `minLeadingWidth: 0` to remove the gap between leading and title and set `horizontalTitleGap: 7` to adjust your custom gap between leading and title.

```
ListTile(
  minLeadingWidth: 0, // min width of leading; if 0 => leading won't take extra space 
  horizontalTitleGap: 7,  //gap between title and leading
  leading: SvgPicture.asset(icChecked),
  title: const Text('Demo Text', style: tsWhiteSemiBold16),
),
```

If you wants your leading in `CenterVertical` , so you have to wrap the leading icon inside a `Container`

```
ListTile(
  minLeadingWidth: 0, // min width of leading; if 0 => leading won't take extra space 
  horizontalTitleGap: 7,  //gap between title and leading
  leading: Container(
    height: double.infinity,
    child: SvgPicture.asset(icChecked),
  ),
  title: const Text('Demo Text', style: tsWhiteSemiBold16),
),
```

You can also user `contentPadding` to adjust the padding of the `ListTile` children.

Answer (score 1):

setting dense true may fix your problem. 
ListTile(
        dense: true
)

Comment: Then the best solution is customise widget using rows.

Comment: This `does not` decrease the margin between `leading` and `title`!!!

Answer (score 0):

If have use Divider for line in ListTile or ListView.separated then set Divider height 0, because Divider take by default some height.

```
Divider(
              height: 0,
        );
```

This is working properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

**After Flutter 2.0 upgrade**

ListTile has received a minLeadingWidth property.
Default value is 40, so to reduce space between leading and title by x pass minLeadingWidth: 40 - x.

Align results will depend on text and tile width.

Use Transform.translate for consistent results.

```
ListTile(
  leading: Icon(icon),
  title: Transform.translate(
    offset: Offset(-16, 0),
    child: Text('Some text'),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As of June 9 of 2021, you can implement that like this, using `horizontalTitleGap`:

```
ListTile(
      horizontalTitleGap: 2,
      title: Text("Title Number ${index + 1}")
)
```