# Remove padding from ListTile between leading and title

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to remove some padding between leading Widget and title Widget in a ListTile.
It has too much blank spaces.
Is there a way to do that?
The code that I am using for that is this:

```
ListTile _getActionMenu(String text, IconData icon, Function() onTap) {
  return new ListTile(
    leading: new Icon(icon),
    title: new Text(text),
    onTap: onTap,
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reduce the margin between 'leading' and 'title' for ListTile ? Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53474168/how-to-reduce-the-margin-between-leading-and-title-for-listtile-flutter)

Comment: With the release of Flutter 2.0.0, it would appear [@Dinesh-Bala's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65411554/638153) would be worthy consideration for this question.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use `Align` and specify the `Alignment`.

```
ListTile _getActionMenu(String text, IconData icon, Function() onTap) {
  return new ListTile(
    leading: new Icon(icon),
    title: Align(
      child: new Text(text),
      alignment: Alignment(-1.2, 0),
    ),
    onTap: onTap,
  );
}
```

Comment: titles became assymetric

Comment: Your solution works but not if I put the Text in a container. I put it in a container because I want to set a background color, but then the Align stops doing anything. Does anyone know a workaround please?

Comment: If the implementation of list tile changes this will cause issues. (e.g the default padding changes in list tile) A better approach is to not use leading and add the required leading widget as part of the title using a row widget. Shown in other answers here.

Answer (score 90):

You can use the **minLeadingWidth** on your ListTile.
The default value is 40, so you can use a lower value to make your leading and title come closer.

```
ListTile(
  leading : Icon(Icons.settings),
  title : Text("Settings"),
  minLeadingWidth : 10,
);
```

Comment: This will be awesome when it's in the Stable channel. As of 2021-03-02 it's in Dev channel. The [edited file's GitHub branch tag](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/8cb266511897d79e6d7d60c08c0e425f4cdaf433#diff-c4ef7c798c820ecda6cab38be1c2d619d5349dc478889f3a54ebbe07f60c11f2) is `1.27.0-8.0.pre` (Stable is [currently at 1.22.6](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases)).

Comment: It's one day later and [`flutter upgrade` just upgraded to `2.0.0`](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases). If I'm reading it right, it would appear this included all Dev (and Beta) channel changes (Dev now has a newer `2.1.0-10.0.pre` build). I'm still on the Stable channel and this option **`minLeadingWidth` is now available**.

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work inside a popup menu, The increment is reflected but not the decrement

Comment: Ok, Sucesso. Exemplo \n ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          minLeadingWidth : defaultPaddingTen,
          leading: Icon(keyPair.value ? Icons.check : Icons.close, color: getCheckColor()),
          title: Text(keyPair.key.toString(), style: GoogleFonts.openSans(fontSize: 16, color: getDescricaoColor())),
        ),

Answer (score 76):

#### EDIT: After Flutter 2.0 upgrade

As Dinesh has pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65411554/4402857), `ListTile` has received a `minLeadingWidth` property.

Default value is `40`, so to reduce space between leading and title by `x` pass `minLeadingWidth: 40 - x`.

---

`Align` results will depend on text and tile width.

Use `Transform.translate` for consistent results.

```dart
ListTile(
  leading: Icon(icon),
  title: Transform.translate(
    offset: Offset(-16, 0),
    child: Text('Some text'),
  ),
);
```

Comment: The @westdabestdb answer worked for me, but only for title. For subtitle only this one worked.

Comment: minLeadingWidth is a better approach

Answer (score 50):

For those who are looking for a clean, one line answer now. You can use

```
ListTile(
 horizontalTitleGap: desiredDoubleValue,
);
```

Comment: Why this answer isn't more up-voted ? Works like a charm along with `minLeadingWidth`.

Comment: also, `minLeadingWidth` has no effect if your leading widget size is bigger than its value. this answer actually does work and removes the space between leading and title padding as the question was asked.

Comment: best answer, only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 35):

this code is the solution

```dart
...
    contentPadding:EdgeInsets.all(0),
...
```

Comment: this reduced the left margin from leading widget only

Answer (score 16):

An *ugly* workaround I've found for this is to put a Row widget in the title section and then put the icon and the text inside that Row with a SizedBox in the middle. This way you can control how much space you want between them:

```
ListView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  children: <Widget>[
    ListTile(
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.android),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5, // here put the desired space between the icon and the text
          ),
          Text("Title") // here we could use a column widget if we want to add a subtitle
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

[image]

Comment: This is not that ugly, less than the accepted answer IMO. At least you can exactly control the padding and it is not dependant on the device aspect ratio.

Comment: I'm a novice, but I agree with @ncuillery - this is a fine solution. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I believe there's gonna be a phantom padding between the null leading and the title of the tile still.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem these days, and finally I published one package which may can solve this problem.

The package is available at https://pub.dev/packages/list_tile_more_customizable, and with this package we can set the horizontalTitleGap, and when it has been set to 0.0(zero), the padding between leading and title will become zero.

Usage:

```
ListTileMoreCustomizable(
    title: Text("Title"),
    trailing: Icon(Icons.people),
    horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
    onTap: (details){},
    onLongPress: (details){},
);
```

Edited:
This method works great for me, and also the code is available at https://github.com/Playhi/list_tile_more_customizable (the raw code is too long) under BSD License, I'm hard to understand why one user down-voted the answer without submitting any problems on it.

Comment: If you rename your package to BetterListTile probably you get upvote :P

Comment: It seems as if these modifications are already merged into Flutter master channel: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/64222

Answer (score 8):

set horizontalTitleGap to 0

```
 ListTile(
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          minLeadingWidth: 5,
                          ***horizontalTitleGap: 0,***
                          leading: widget,
                          title: widget ,
                         )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 6):

Use **horizontalTileGap:**

```
ListTile(
        horizontalTitleGap: 0,
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 50,
          backgroundImage:
              NetworkImage("https://picsum.photos/250?image=1"),
        ),
        title: Text("Image 6"),
      ),
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead, you can create your own Widget as below:

1. Let's say we'll create a widget file called `text_icon.dart`

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

      class TextIcon extends StatelessWidget {
        final String title;
        final IconData icon;
        final String button;

        const TextIcon({Key key, this.title, this.icon, this.button}) : super(key: key);

        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          final theme = Theme.of(context);

          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 24.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                 icon,
                 size: 18,
                ),
               SizedBox(width: 5),
               Text(
                 title,
                 style: theme.textTheme.subhead.copyWith(fontSize: 13),
               ),
             ],
           ),
         );
       }
     }
```

2. Call your widget in your screen

   ```
   TextIcon(icon: Icons.pause_circle_filled, title: "John Doe")
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Now ListTile has the property of minLeadingWidth.

Example

```
ListTile(
      minLeadingWidth: 15,
      leading: Icons(Icons.search),
      title: Text("Data");
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be solved by simply adding: `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,`

Answer (score 2):

You must to add this parameter.

```
return ListTile(
    leading: new Icon(icon),
    title: new Text(text),
    onTap: onTap,
    //Add this parameter
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a `ListTile` is not the correct widget a more elegant approach would be:

```dart
FlatButton.icon(
    onPressed: null,
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.flag_rounded,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    label: Text('Title'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is enough to adjust the gap between the title and leading

```
horizontalTitleGap: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
horizontalTitleGap: value,
minLeadingWidth: value,
```

use the two together. Works pefectly. the values have to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me. Keep the minLeadingWidth as 0, and adjust the horizontalTitleGap to acheive the desired output.

```
return ListTile(
    leading: new Icon(icon),
    title: new Text(text),
    horizontalTitleGap: 8,
    minLeadingWidth: 0,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,  // Remove padding before leading icon
        horizontalTitleGap: -14.0,  // Reduce padding between title and leading icon 
      ),
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Segue exemplo

```
ListTile(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      minLeadingWidth : defaultPaddingTen,
      leading: Icon(keyPair.value ? Icons.check : Icons.close, color: getCheckColor()),
      title: Text(keyPair.key.toString(), style: GoogleFonts.openSans(fontSize: 16, color: getDescricaoColor())),
    ),
```