# How to shorten padding around leading in ListTile?

Tags: flutter

Please refer to my codes and screenshot below, there are spaces on both left and right sides with a leading icon. I guess it is the default layout with leading in `ListTile` or `LayoutBuilder`, anyway, how can I shorten these spaces or `Padding`?

```
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      child: Card(
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0)),
        ),
        child: ListTile(
          horizontalTitleGap: 0,
          minLeadingWidth :  10,
          leading: assetId != null
              ? Container(
                  width: 150,
                  height: 150,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                    color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)),
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  child: LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (context, constraints) {
                      return Image.asset(
                        iconPass,
                        fit: BoxFit.none,
                        scale: 5,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                )
              : null,
          title: Text(
            name,
            style: MyText(myFontSize: 15).style(),
          ),
          subtitle: subTitle,
          trailing: iconNavigator(
            destinationTo: cards(),
            context: context,
            backForward: "forward",
            myIcon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please shorten your screenshot, it is excessively tall.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and how is it look like ? seems to be better ?

Comment: use 'horizontalTitleGap'

Comment: thanks for your comment and I set 0 for the property 'horizontalTitleGap' but could not remove spaces.

Comment: refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154119/remove-padding-from-listtile-between-leading-and-title)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I actually referred to the article and tried several ways suggested, but finally could not remove the both left and right spaces like screenshot shown at the bottom of my original inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

The `padding` you are witnessing is because flutter is trying to expand the widget in all four directions and then trying to `fit` it inside the `leading` widget , To overcome this try wrapping your `leading` with `SizedBox` and give it a `fixed width`.

```
 leading: SizedBox(width: 60, child: <Your Widget here>),
```

##### Before `SizedBox`:

[image]

##### After applying `SizedBox`:

[image]

##### Code:

```
Center(
              child: Column(
            children: const [
              Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: SizedBox(width: 60, child: FlutterLogo(size: 56.0)),
                  title: Text('Two-line ListTile'),
                  subtitle: Text('Here is a second line'),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: SizedBox(width: 60, child: FlutterLogo(size: 72.0)),
                  title: Text('Three-line ListTile'),
                  subtitle: Text(
                      'A sufficiently long subtitle warrants three lines.'),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                  // isThreeLine: true,
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: SizedBox(width: 60, child: FlutterLogo(size: 128.0)),
                  title: Text('Three-line ListTile'),
                  subtitle: Text(
                      'A sufficiently long subtitle warrants three lines.'),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
```