# How to Remove space at top and bottom ListTile flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

How to remove the space top and bottom from `ListTile`?

My Code is:

```
 child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      ListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0),
        title: Text(
          'Home',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
        ),
      ),
      ListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0),
        title: Text(
          'Audio',
          style:
              TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.black45),
        ),
      ),),
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `ListTile` it is not possible. Some modifications are possible with the help of `ListTileTheme` like color and there is also the option of modifying padding but only work for left and right padding. So better is to create your own custom tile as @santosh showed in his answer.
You can also use SizedBox but it can result in tragic output.

Comment: Yes, it is possible using `visualDensity`. 
Check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63504719/6747251

Answer (score 85):

**UPDATE**

Now you can also use the following propertier:

1. `horizontalTitleGap` - Between *title* and *leading*
2. `minVerticalPadding` - Between *title* and *subtitle*
3. `minLeadingWidth` - Minimum width of *leading*
4. `contentPadding` - Internal padding

**OLD**

You can use the `visualDensity` property to reduce the space.

```
ListTile(
    visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: -4),
    title: Text("xyz")
);
```

The  `visualDensity` value can be changed from `-4.0 to 4.0`. Lower the value, more compact the view.

P.S. This solution is similar to a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63504801/6747251)

*This question is about the `top/bottom` spacing. But the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63504801/6747251) is about gap between `leading` and `title`*

Comment: I'm not able to find this "visualDensity" in my ListTile widget properties!!!

Comment: solved 50% space, still have 6-8 pixels gap between top of Listtile and content.

Comment: @Kamlesh you can create a custom list tile , if you need more flexibility

Comment: visualDensity can reduce height between ListTiles

Comment: minVerticalPadding worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 49):

In your code put property dense: true inside the list tile

```
       ListTile(
                dense:true,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0),
                title: Text(
                  'Home',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                ),
              ),
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It only removes horizontal padding, not vertical ones.

Comment: "dense: true" alone did decrement the vertical spacing. but content padding didn't work for vertical spacing issue

Comment: Adding fontSize along with other settings did help to reduce the top padding

Answer (score 22):

```
ListTile(
    dense: true,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: 0.0),
    visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: -4),
);
```

Above solution worked for me. I hope, this will also help you. Thanks for asking this question.

Answer (score 12):

That worked for me in ListTile:

```
visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: -4)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Home',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Audio',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.black45),
                    ),
                 ),)
```

Answer (score 3):

this is worked for me

```
ListTile(
  dense:true,
  minVerticalPadding: 0,
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: 4),
        );
```

now I have no padding at all

Answer (score 3):

```dart
ListTile(
  minVerticalPadding: 0, // else 2px still present
  dense: true, // else 2px still present
  visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact, // Else theme will be use
  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.zero, // Or what do you want, you will have now the exact amount of padding as expected
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try with shorter way:

```
ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          dense: true,
          title: Text('label'),
        );
```

Comment: `contentPadding` helped me to remove left right space

Answer (score 1):

```
ListTile(
  dense: true,
  visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: -4),
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0,right: 0.0, top: 0.0),
  title:  LabelText(
    labelText: "Cara",
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
    color: AppColor.txtColor,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center
  ),
  subtitle:  LabelText(
    labelText: "Patient #1",
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
    color: AppColor.inactive,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center
  ),
),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

For me Padding widget worked in place of ListTile.padding variable can be updated as per your requirements for a ListItem.

```
Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left : 8.0 , right 8.0),
        child: Text("List Item Text",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1))
```

Answer (score -1):

None of the solutions above will work (for now). Your best bet is to use a `TextButton` and include a `Row` as the child