# How do I remove the default padding from a SizedBox in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How would I remove the padding that's present here in the `SizedBox` widget that wraps each button:

[image]

I tried, as you can see in the code, to set the padding of the container that is wrapped BY the SizedBox equal to 0 but it didn't work. I basically just want to make each SizedBox smaller so that the content inside is closer to each other. I was wondering if there was any workaround for doing so.

```
Container( // container holding the main setting buttons
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 0, left: 30, right: 30),
    child: Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2.5),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 7, top: 7, right: 10, bottom: 8),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Material(color: Colors.transparent,
            child: SizedBox(width: 250.0, child: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, child: ListTile(onTap:(){}, title:Text("Privacy"),leading: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline)))),
          ),
          Material(
            child: SizedBox(width: 250.0, child: ListTile(onTap:(){},title:Text("Terms of Service"),leading: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline))),
          ),
          Material(
            child: SizedBox(width: 250.0, child: ListTile(onTap:(){},title:Text("Community Rules"),leading: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline))),
          ),
        ]
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't relates to your `SizedBox`, it belongs to `ListTile`.

About `ListTile`, you can check out [How to Remove space at top and bottom ListTile flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265313/how-to-remove-space-at-top-and-bottom-listtile-flutter) and [Remove padding from ListTile between leading and title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154119/remove-padding-from-listtile-between-leading-and-title).

`Icon(Icons.abcxyz)` may also contain a little margin because of their design, you should also notice.