# How to set the padding between leading and title from Flutter ListTile?

Tags: flutter

i have a compromise solution below which do not satisfy me .

```
final int padding=10; //the padding you wanna set.
ListTile(
    leading: Icon(icon),
    title:  Container(
                  height: 30,
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    overflow: Overflow.visible,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Positioned(
                        child: title,
                        left: padding-35,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
 );
```

yes. you can use the negative margin. which definitely works. but it is not perfect .so could anyone offer a better solution ?

========= Additional ===========

i see some answer below .but it seems you do not get my points.

the default padding between leading and title from Flutter ListTile is too large for me. i wanna adjust the padding by myself . and just wrapping the title with Padding widget can not achieve the goal .

**========= A better solution i found ===========**

```
final int padding = 10; //the padding you wanna set.
ListTile(
  leading: Icon(icon),
  title: Container(
    transform: Matrix4.translationValues(padding - 35, 0.0, 0.0),
    child: title,
  ),
);
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @RayLi  thanks for your reply. which make me feel good .haha

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Material is so very frustrating with the hardcoded values like mines everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Use Padding widget like :

```
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                  title: Padding(
                    // change left : 
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                    child: Text('hello world'),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding to your title widget for this.

Replace your code with:

```
final double padding=10; //the padding you wanna set.
ListTile(
    leading: Icon(icon),
    title: Padding(
             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(padding),
             child:Container(
             height: 30,
             child: Stack(
               alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
               overflow: Overflow.visible,
               children: <Widget>[
                 Positioned(
                   child: title,
                   left: padding-35,
                 ),
               ],
             ),
           ),
         ),
 );
```